# Magento 2 Order print showing href links with content!

Tags: sales-order, customer-account, magento2.3.2, pdf, print

I have social links in footer in the website, and configured url in admin configuration for social icons.

But when I am printing order PDF from customer account order view page then all links on the pdf are showing seperated with icons.

Links which are in anchor href must not be shown here.

Check Screenshot: [links are visible in pdf](https://nimb.ws/SvwIVe)